# Javascript error."Syntax Error, unrecognized expression:access key=[]

Tags: javascript

[image]

Below is the line of code at line number 267

```
var itemCollection = BuildXmlFromString(preXML).selectNodes('root/*');
```

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Seeing as it looks unlikely that the error is actually on that line, can you search your source code for "access-key"?

Comment: Let's see the line # 267 from view source of the page? Your source code line #s are different than actual line #s once rendered